# Issue closing Boost Asio Acceptor

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, boost-asio, tcpserver

I am facing an issue trying to close an asio ip::tcp::acceptor. Following is the code that I am using (loosely based on the [async server example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp03/echo/async_tcp_echo_server.cpp)) to start and run the tcp listener/server:

To start the service:

```
bool TCPServer::listen()
{
    try
    {
        if(std::atoi(_port.c_str()) <= 0)
        {
            LOG_ERROR("Configured port is invalid. Application will not work. Please check config file.");
            return false;
        }

        int noOfThreads = 5;

        using namespace boost::asio::ip;

        tcp::endpoint endpoint(address::from_string(_host), std::atoi(_port.c_str()));
        _acceptor.reset(new tcp::acceptor(_ioService, endpoint));

        startAccept();

        for(std::size_t i = 0; i < static_cast<unsigned>(noOfThreads); ++i)
        {
            _threads.push_back(std::thread(std::bind(static_cast<size_t (boost::asio::io_service::*)()>
                (&boost::asio::io_service::run), &_ioService)));
        }

        return true;
    }
    catch(std::exception& e)
    {
        LOG_ERROR("Received exception while trying to listen at the specified address. Please verify the address"
            << " is accurate. Exception:" << e.what());
        return false;
    }
}
```

Following is the startAccept() function called in the above code. It starts an object of class "TCPConnection" and queues it to the asio queue.:

```
void TCPServer::startAccept()
{
    TCPConnection::Ptr newConn(new TCPConnection(_acceptor->get_io_service(), _processDataFn));

    _acceptor->async_accept(newConn->socket(), std::bind(&TCPServer::handleAccept, this, newConn, std::placeholders::_1));
}
```

And Following is the handleAccept() function asynchronously called by asio as specified in the startAccept() function:

```
void TCPServer::handleAccept(TCPConnection::Ptr newConn_, const boost::system::error_code& error_)
{
    if (!error_)
    {
        newConn_->start();
    }
    else
    {
        LOG_ERROR("Encountered error while trying to accept connection. Error Code:" << error_);
    }
    startAccept();
}
```

The above code seems to be working fine and listening fine. The problem I am facing is regarding the closing of the server. I am using the following code to close the server.

```
TCPServer::~TCPServer()
{
    try
    {
        if(!_ioService.stopped())
        {
            _ioService.stop();
        }

        if(_acceptor)
        {
            boost::system::error_code ec;
            _acceptor->cancel(ec);
            _acceptor->close(ec);
        }

        for(std::size_t i = 0; i < _threads.size(); ++i)
        {
            if(_threads[i].joinable())
            {
                _threads[i].join();
            }
        }

        //_acceptor.reset(); // Hacky and causes memory leak.

    }
    catch(std::exception& e_)
    {
        LOG_ERROR("Received exception while shutting down listener. Exception:" << e_.what());
    }
}
```

The trouble is that in the above code, if the commented line is not uncommented, the thread from which this function is called does not return. If the commented line is uncommented it causes memory leak (The leaked items are member variables of acceptor). Note that the app is a simple GUI app (I am using wxWidgets). The above listen() function and destructor is called from its gui threads at various events (I am not sure that is relevant. But just in case...). I have been struggling at this for hours now. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need to explicitly stop `io_service`? Just close the acceptor and the sockets (sessions) and wait until `io_service` runs out of work.

Comment: I commented out the code to stop the io_service. But it doesn't seem to make any difference. Also while testing this, I am not receiving any connection.